# Advertising and connection establishment using nRF52 DK with nrf52832 chip on Segger Embedded studio

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to know how to send out an advertisement with some specific user number and data such that a connection can be established using the the sdk 15.3.0.
could anyone suggest me what changes i need to make in the ble app beacon code given in the sdk examples.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to start with the ble_peripheral example of the Nordic SDK.
You can find the following two guides on their forum : https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/nordic/short-range-guides/b/bluetooth-low-energy/posts/ble-services-a-beginners-tutorial and https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/nordic/short-range-guides/b/bluetooth-low-energy/posts/ble-characteristics-a-beginners-tutorial

This explains how to build a custom service with a custom characteristic to handle read / write and notification of values from the embedded device to a BLE central device (e.g: smartphone).